# neo4j creates duplicate nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following users csv:

```
email,ip
abc@hotmail.com,73.53.30.159
xyz@gmail.com,1.2.3.4
abc@hotmail.com,1.1.1.1
```

And the following ips csv:

```
ip
73.53.30.159
1.1.1.1
```

Im creating the 2 node types using:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///ips2.csv" AS row
CREATE (:IP {ip: row.ip});
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///ips2.csv" AS row
CREATE (:IP {ip: row.ip});
```

and

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///emails.csv" AS row
CREATE (:A1USER {email: row.email, ip: row.ip});
```

Then, i want to create a connection between users with a given ip to the corresponding ip node:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///emails.csv" AS row
MATCH (u:USER {email: row.email, ip:row.ip})
MATCH (ip:IP {ip: row.ip})
MERGE (ip)-[:ACCESSED]->(u);
```

however, in my example, the "abc@hotmail.com" is being created twice, once accessed by 1.1.1.1 and once accessed by 73.53.30.159.
I expect the "abc@hotmail.com" node to be created once and have two incoming relationships, one from 1.1.1.1 and one from 73.53.30.159.

How should I go about that?
Thanks.

Comment: In your "creating the 2 node types" query, you are loading from the same CSV file twice and also creating instances of the same node type twice. Is this a typo, or is this your actual query?

Answer (score 1):

In your import files, if the same data can occur more than once, use MERGE instead of CREATE when you make the nodes.

I'm assuming you have unique constraints on :IP(ip) and :IP9(ip)? You'll need either a unique constraint or an index on :USER(email), depending on if the same email can be used by more than one user.

Comment: In my import files, the same email can occur more than once. I tried to replace CREATE with MERGE but I still get duplicate nodes with the same email.

Comment: And yes, I have unique constraint on IP(ip) and INDEX on USER(email).

Comment: Are the duplicate nodes really duplicates? Or are there other property differences? Also, I noticed you're using :USER and :A1USER nodes, is the duplication between nodes with these labels, or just in one label or the other?

Answer (score 1):

Your users CSV contains duplicate email addresses, with different IP addresses: it doesn't make sense to store the IP address as a node property, since there are several of them and you're going to create a relationship with an `IP` node anyway.

Just create the `IP` nodes first, then connect directly the `USER` node at creation (from the email address only):

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:IP) ASSERT n.ip IS UNIQUE;
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:USER) ASSERT n.email IS UNIQUE;

USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///ips2.csv" AS row
CREATE (:IP {ip: row.ip});

USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///emails.csv" AS row
// Merge on the "primary key" only
MERGE (u:USER {email: row.email})
WITH row, u
MATCH (ip:IP {ip: row.ip})
MERGE (ip)-[:ACCESSED]->(u);
```